# Display database into a table- html

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I have an index page and I wrote a php code inside of this index page.This is the code of php what I have written.I want with that way to display my database table named players.The lib/connect2.php is the connection and work fine,is ok this.First, I know from php I can do that require_once lib/connect2.I don't know if .html is working..Anyway,the code after require_once is wrong I think..but I can't see where I am wrong..

```
<div id="D5">
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>piece_color</th>
<th>token</th>
</tr>
</div>
<?php
require_once "lib/connect2.php";
    
    $sql = "SELECT username, piece_color, token FROM players";
    $result = $mysqli-> query($sql);
    
    if($result-> num_rows >0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr><td>". $row["username"] ."</td><td>". $row["piece_color"] ."</td><td>". $row["token"] ."</td></tr>"};
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
    else{
    echo "0 result";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    
    ?>
```

**Edited:**  I am trying to do that video youtube.com/watch?v=bHFoobciCTM&t=14s . Ofcourse with my database..my database connection is in lib/connect2.php.After that I am using the code I see in this video and it doesnt work..I don't know why.The error I get is that it display me this on id=D5 this message" Username piece_color token ". $row["username"] ." ". $row["piece_color"] ." ". $row["token"] ." "; } else{ echo "0 result"; } $mysqli->close(); ?>" .

**The expectation**: was to display-show my database ..my database has username,piece_color,token and last_action. The last_action is time stamp and I didn't use it on my code.So I use the 3 columns from my database(username,piece_color,token)

Comment: Sorry it's not clear specifically what the problem is. Are you experiencing an error or something? Please try to clarify your exact issue.

Comment: @ADyson Hi ! I am trying to do that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHFoobciCTM&t=14s . Ofcourse with my database..my database connection is  in lib/connect2.php.After that I am using the code I see in this video and it doesnt work..I don't know why.The error I get is that it display me this on id=D5 this message" Username piece_color token
". $row["username"] ." ". $row["piece_color"] ." ". $row["token"] ."
"; } else{ echo "0 result"; } $mysqli->close(); ?>"

Comment: The expectation was to display-show my database ..my database has username,piece_color,token and last_action. The last_action is time stamp and  I didn't use it on my code.So I use the 3 columns from my database(username,piece_color,token)

Comment: Sorry can you use the "edit" button of your question to put that information into your question so it's formatted properly and easier to understand? It's important info which should not be just in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson ok I am on the way to edited

Comment: Are you saying it shows some of your PHP code on the screen instead of executing it? Perhaps you didn't install PHP in the webserver? Or perhaps you didn't give the file a .php extension?

Comment: By the way your HTML is not valid...you can't have a `</div>` in the middle of a table. That needs to go right at the end of all your code I think, after the PHP.

Comment: @ADyson about your first comment all I have done. about the second comment for html I go delete </div>

Comment: it is .html extension..It can't work if it is .html?

Comment: No. Because the webserver won't pass it to the PHP interpreter to be executed. Rename it to .php and try again.

Comment: @ADyson  this line is wrong it says "syntax error " -> echo "<tr><td>". $row["username"] ."</td><td>". $row["piece_color"] ."</td><td>". $row["token"] ."</td></tr>"};

Comment: P.s. you shouldn't delete the `</div>` unless you also delete the `<div id=D5>` which it belongs with. Just move it to the end, was my suggestion, so it wraps around the whole table.

Comment: Well that's better, if you get a syntax error it shows PHP is now examining your code and trying to execute it. If you're using an IDE or code editor which has syntax highlighting then it should help you to see where the mistake is

Comment: But I can tell you, you have a random stray `}` just before the end of that line. Always double check your work and always use a good code editor.

Comment: @ADyson I fix that,thanks but it stills shows me that :/

Comment: @ADyson it work man thank you <3 .Please give a simple answer as to accept it .You help me a lot .I appreciate your help much